# Changing color of custom listview item on focus

Tags: android, listview, colors, focus

I have created a custom list and managed to change the colors of the child items in normal and clicked view. But When I apply it to the focus view, then nothing happens and the default background color only gets displayed with the changed color of the text from white to black. Here are the xml files that I am using for what I have done so far.

Layout for listview (listview.xml)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:padding="18sp"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundselector">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
    <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10sp" android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

clicked.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
   <solid android:color="#ffc61212" />
 </shape>
```

focussed.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
   <solid android:color="#ff26e0d7" />
 </shape>
```

normal.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
   <solid android:color="#ff0a4d66" />
 </shape>
```

and finally backgroundselector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/focussed" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/clicked" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/normal" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Please I need help on how can I change the color of the child item of my list view when a child item is focussed...

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to override `ListView.onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)` method, which will be called when an item is clicked.

And in this method, you can create a new ArrayAdapter. Like this:
`ArrayAdapter<String> adpater=new ArrayAdapter<String>(CurrentActivity.this,R.layout.foucs,data);` where data is an object array used to provide data for the ListView(generally, we use String[] or ArrayList class).

And then, call `ListView.setAdapter(adapter)` to show your new style.

Hope it helps. I am a greedhand:)

Ah, I find a new and convenient way to do this.

In `ListView.onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)` method,
just call `arg1.setBackgroundColor(newColor);` to change the color of the item.

Comment: But this is for when the child node of the listview will be clicked. I was expecting something when the child item is focussed and it's color would change... Anyways thanks for the help.